# Powershell write-out actual matching strings instead of the whole line

Tags: powershell

I'm about to rewrite a bunch of css files. (px to rem). Therefore I've written a oneliner, that searches for numbers followed by the string"px" and writes them out to a txt-file. Yet my script "select-string -path ".\media\scss\2022-04-24-customScreen-v1.scss" -Pattern '[0-9]*px' | select line | out-file outputfile.txt -append" always gives me back the whole line (because I use select line) and I get something like "Line                                                  "
$fs-2: 14px;
$lh-1: 22px;
$mw: 1260px;   ..."
How do I write-out only the entry itself without the rst of its line like
"14px
22px
1260px"
and so on. What is the equivalent to "select line" if I do only want the entry itself?

Comment: Try `(Select-String -Path ".\media\scss\2022-04-24-customScreen-v1.scss" -Pattern '[0-9]*px;' -AllMatches).Matches.Value`

Comment: Wow! First time I asked a question here and I received a perfect answer immediatly. Thank you very much, Theo!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be of help